# Solve the equation: $\frac{z}{z-5}+\frac{1}{3}=-\frac{5}{5-z}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation: $\frac{z}{z-5}+\frac{1}{3}=-\frac{5}{5-z}$

First $z$ cannot be equal to $5$.

First, I multiplied $z$ with $3$, $1$ with $z-5$ and $-5$ with both. Eliminating the denominators gives me:$3z + z-5 = - 15$. Simplified, I'm left with: $4z-5=-15$.

Somehow I don't see how this can be solved. If it were $15$, I could at least say that $4\cdot5-5=15$. But that there aren't any solutions because $z$ cannot be $5$.

What am I not seeing?

Comment: You made an algebra error when you multiplied by $3(z-5)$: the denominator of the RHS is $5-z$, so you pick up another minus sign which gives you 15 (as you expected.) ...problem is, the only solution to that is $z=5$.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I did wrong! Then it can't be solved as I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move everything to one side. z-5 and 5-z eliminate each other. There is no letter z left. As you said yourself z=5 has no solution. That's the reason why this equation can not be solved.

Comment: I got it thanks. Z is cancelled and 1/3=0 is worthless on itself.

Answer (score 4):

This equation has no solution. Change sides to see that

$$\frac{z}{z-5}+(1/3)+\frac{5}{5-z}=0 \\
Or,\frac{z}{z-5}+(1/3)+\frac{-5}{z-5}=0 \\
Or, \frac{z-5}{z-5}+(1/3)=0$$

Which is impossible.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding your method. Can you show it the way I wrote the question? I understand that you moved it to the other side.

Comment: Edited for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You made a sign error when you tried to clear denominators.

If you multiply the entire equation by $3(z-5)$, the right-hand side should be $3(z-5)\left(-\frac{5}{5-z}\right)=-15\left(\frac{z-5}{5-z}\right)=15$. If you fix this mistake, you'll be left with a simplified equation whose only solution is $z=5$, which doesn't work in the original equation.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Semiclassical already told me in a comment :)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like we were writing simultaneously...